# Rails Set child association id to nil when deleting parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

This is my association set up between my `Collection` and `Album` models:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, class_name: "Collection", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Collection", foreign_key: "parent_id", optional: true
  has_many :albums
end
```

---

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :collection, optional: true
end
```

I've just deleted all the `Collection`'s, and I expected the `collection_id` of each `Album` to be returned to `NULL` as the parent no longer exists.

How can I make sure this happens when an `Album`'s parent `Collection` is deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dependent: nullify` in your `Collection` model:

```
has_many :albums, dependent: :nullify
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly it.

Answer (score 1):

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many

You need to `nullify` the association foreign_key